# Mercurial template: separator for tags and bookmarks

Tags: templates, mercurial

Can I put space characters as separators only if I have any Tag or Bookmark?

Example:

```
hg log --template "{rev} {author} {tags} {bookmarks} {desc|firstline}\n"

Output:
3: Author1 TIP BKMRK_NAME Another commit
2: Author1   Third commit
1: Author1 TAG1  Second commit
0: Author1   Initial commit
```

The changesets that don't have Tags or Bookmarks prints the space characters. I'd like to suppress those extra spaces:

```
3: Author1 TAG_NAME BKMRK_NAME Another commit
2: Author1 Third commit
1: Author1 TAG1 Second commit
0: Author1 Initial commit
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A new style can be created that defines how the start of a collection (i.e. bookmarks), the element in the collection itself and the last element of a collection look like.

Save the following style definition in a file e.g. called "my_style":

```
changeset = '{rev} {author}{bookmarks} {desc|firstline}\n'

start_bookmarks = ' ['
bookmark = '{bookmark}, '
last_bookmark = '{bookmark}]'
```

You then can call hg log with the just newly created style:

```
> hg log --style /path/to/my_style
6 james [bar, foo, master] b 3
5 james b 2
4 james a 3
```

This would only insert a space and bracket if there are bookmarks at all (note that there's no space between {author} and {bookmarks}).

Some nice cli templates as reference can be found [here](https://bitbucket.org/sjl/mercurial-cli-templates).

Comment: Yes, that's it. I think I tried something like that before but I included just the "start_bookmarks = ..." line. This line alone doesn't work. The "bookmark = ..." line is needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

With a recent Mercurial (after 2.5), you can use the `if` template expression:

```
hg log --template '{rev} {author}{if(tags, " {tags}")}{if(bookmarks," {bookmarks}")} {desc|firstline}\n'
```

Answer (score 2):

I don’t know much about templating in Mercurial, but you can always filter out the extra spaces with `sed`:

```
hg log --template "{rev} {author} {tags} {bookmarks} {desc|firstline}\n" | sed "s/  */ /g"
```

Comment: Unfortunately that's not a solution for me because I made a style out of a template like this. I need to do this in Mercurial because it's the default style for commands like "hg log -l 10", "hg heads", etc... Also removing all the double spaces would mess the graphic of glog.